# Passing state from ajax from one component to another

Tags: javascript, reactjs, components, state

I have a component where a user clicks a button they go to another page (`localhost:3020 --> localhost:3020/python`).  I want to make an ajax request using a url entered into the input box in `App.js` to a Python script that returns a JSON object, which is then stored into the `posts` array.  Then I want to pass values within the `post` array to `PythonComponent.js` when the button is clicked.  When I enter a url & click the link, my `console.log` statement shows up in the console but I don't see any text from `posts` rendered.

If I create a dummy variable in state for `App.js`, update the state with the text from the input box, the input box text will be rendered on `localhost:3020/python`.  It doesn't work when I'm trying to return `posts` after making the ajax call.

My question is how can I pass `posts` from `App.js` to `PythonComponent.js?`

App.js

```
class App extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      posts=[]
    };
    this.handleClick = this.handleClick.bind(this);
  }

  handleClick () {
    const urlBox = document.getElementById("box").value;
    this.setState({
      sendText: urlBox,
    })

    $.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    data: { arg1: urlBox} ,
    url: "http://127.0.0.1:5000/hello/",
    }).done(function(res) {
      this.setState({posts:res
      });
      console.log(res.title, res.text)
    }.bind(this));
  }


  render() {
    return (
        <div className="App">
            <div>
            <p className = "input-title"> Enter a URL</p>
            <input placeholder = "placeholder text" id="box" ref="textBox" type="text"/>
            <button onClick={this.handleClick}>
               <Link to={{pathname:"/python", message: this.state.posts.title}}> cant use button have to use link text </Link>
            </button>
          </div>
        </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

index.js

```
 <BrowserRouter>
   <Switch>
     <Route path='/python' component={PythonComponent} />
      <Route path='/' component={App} />
   </Switch>
</BrowserRouter>
```

PythonComponent.js

```
class PythonComponent extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <Link to={{pathname:"/"}}> home </Link>
        <h1> HI </h1>
        {this.props.location.message} 
      </div>
    );
  }
}
export default PythonComponent;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First thing I noticed is you're missing part of the constructor for the App component. Maybe just a copy/paste mistake?

```
class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      posts=[]
    };
    this.handleClick = this.handleClick.bind(this);
  }
  ...
```

Secondly, if App is only making the Ajax request to get data for the PythonComponent, I would move that call to the PythonComponent and let it handle the request and render cycle responsibility. You could put that request inside the [componentDidMount lifecycle hook](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#componentdidmount). Once the request resolves and you set the state, the render function will fire again.

The reason I suggest moving the request to the PythonComponent is by the time the user clicks the `Link` component, it has already redirected the user *before* the AJAX request resolves. So there's no data available to the PythonComponent. By moving it, the redirect occurs and the PythonComponent will mount, fetching the data it needs and then re-render once the state updates.

And thirdly, when you're using `Link`, to pass state to the linked component, you'll want to use the `state` prop. For example:

```
<Link to={{
  pathname: '/python',
  state: { message: 'Hello!' }
}}/>
```

See the [Link documentation](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/blob/master/packages/react-router-dom/docs/api/Link.md) for more details.

Hope this helps!